# JTabbedPane problem - panel shows through when updated even when not focused

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm writing a video application in Java which also incorporates a drawing area. The interface consists of a Frame containing a JTabbedPane with two panes: the first contains thmubnails of images sent by other computers, and the other pane contains a drawing area.

The program is networked and when a user draws on their drawing area, the information is sent to other users and their own drawing area updates. The problem I have though, is that when this happens, the new drawing area image is then painted onto the interface panel - regardless of whether the user is actually viewing the drawing area pane or not.
I.e. even if I am looking at the thumbnails panel, the new drawing will paint onto the thumbnails panel.

Any ideas why this might be happening? Thanks.

As a note it is something to do with the JTabbedPane, because when I run the drawing area in a separate frame there is no problem.

Comment: are you invoking paint(Graphics g) directly anywhere?

Comment: to do the drawing i assume you have overridden the paintComponents method of some JPanel that is in side the tabbed pane?